# Wait for function with callback

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I know this has been asked multiple times. And I've been through many of the answers. But no answer did work for me. Code was running and didn't wait for the callback / promise resolve etc. Or it was waiting forever for the callback.

So I have a function that calles an asynchronous function Files.load() with a callback and Files.load() doesn't return a promise:

```
function loadfile(url) {
  ...

  Files.load(url),options, (error, file) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      return file;
    }
  }
}
```

So i tried to build a promise wrapper;

```
function loadFileWrapper(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    loadFile(fileObj, (successResponse) => {
      resolve(successResponse); // this was never executed
    }, (errorResponse) => {
      reject(errorResponse); // neither this
    });
  });
}
```

And called it in an async funtion

```
async function fileParsing() {
  const file = await loadFileWrapper(file);
  // code here should wait after loadFileWrapper returns a value?
}
```

Can someone help me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Inside the promise wrapper you have `loadFile` instead of `Files.load`. Is that a typo? Or do you actually have that in code? It should be `Files.load`. Promise wrapper needs to be around the callback-based asynchronous function which in your case if `Files.load`.

Comment: Hey, yes i have it like that in the code. I will try to refactor it.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. I thought it is possible to call the outer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So i tried to build a promise wrapper
>
> ```
> loadFile(fileObj, (successResponse) => {
> ```

Now you are passing **two** arguments to `loadFile`, but `loadFile` only takes **one** argument.

You need to wrap `Files.load` (i.e. the function which actually performs the asynchronous operation and which accepts a callback) with a promise, not `loadFile`.

---

```js
function loadfile(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Files.load(url ,options, (error, file) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      } else {
        return resolve(file);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Worked. I thought it is possible to use the outer function for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with 2 approaches, I personally prefer a promise-based approach because we can use async/await.

**add a callback to loadfile function**

```
function loadfile(url, cb) {
  // ...
  Files.load(url, options, cb);
}
```

**Promise approach**

```
function loadfile(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Files.load(url, options, (error, file) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(file);
      }
    });
  });
}
```